# Multiple strokes with spacing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I want to have a button style with two strokes with some spacing between them. My first approach is not satisfying because in the corners the spacing between the strokes is different:

[image]

The gray stroke should be tight around the blue gradient and the corner radius of the white stroke should fit to the others.

Here's my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#7F7F7F"/>

            <corners
                android:radius="6dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"/>

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorBlueLight"
                android:endColor="@color/colorBlueDark"
                android:angle="270"/>

            <corners
                android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

            <corners
                android:radius="6dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... that's how geometry works.

[image]

Distance `A` is not equal to `B` as long as you keep the same corner `radius` for inner and outer rounded rectangle.

What you can do is to try to "hide" this effect by modifying the inner corner `radius` to a smaller value. Find a proper value that satisfies your needs (I used `4dp` in the code below as an example).

```
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <padding android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp"/>

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

        <corners
            android:radius="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And with the smaller inner `radius`:

[image]